# Angular switch in repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given a list such as

```
var list = ['one','two','three'];
```

In angular, I want to iterate through the list only rendering certain items. Something like:

```
<ul ng-controller="main">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-switch on="item">
        <span ng-switch-when="one">{{item}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And have the output look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>one</span></li>
</ul>
```

Instead, I get:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>one</span></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried ng-hide but is woefully inefficient since I have a large number of items and only want to display one or two and ng-hide renders all of them and then hides the inactive ones with css. This is a problem because I am doing this in a JQuery Mobile app which tries to decorate all list items, including the hidden ones, killing performance.

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ghendricks/MXu3a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `ng-hide` should not be used here, it is a job for [filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter).
You can provide a custom function to filter the list: http://jsfiddle.net/ERMVj/

```js
$scope.selectOne = function (input) { return input == "two" || input == "one"; };
```

```
    <li ng-repeat="l in list | filter:selectOne">
        <span>{{l}}</span>
    </li>
```